# How to Remove Empty Row Elements from Multiple Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I Posted group of Product Information using Array. Some time Empty row has been inserted. how to remove this.

[image]

Client Side Code :

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<6; $i++) { ?>
<input type="text" name="product[]" id="product{{$i}}">
<input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty{{$i}}">
<input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate{{$i}}">
<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount{{$i}}">
<?php } ?>
```

Server Side Code :

```
 $product=implode('#@$',$_POST["product"]);
    $qty=implode('#@$',$_POST["qty"]);
    $rate=implode('#@$',$_POST["rate"]);
    $amts=implode('#@$',$_POST["amount"]);

$insertqry=mysql_query("insert into invoice (prodt,qty,rates,amts) values('$product','$qty','$rate','$amts')");
```

Comment: what's the basis that you are saying the marked one is  empty?

Comment: Some Times user Not Fill that Row. if Row Empty Can't Insert the Value @AlivetoDie

Comment: Wrap everything in the for loop inside a IF statement...?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you define a row to be empty, if empty product name is empty row,
then:

add a condition  `if ($product == '') continue;`

before:

`$insertqry=mysql_query("insert into invoice (prodt,qty,rates,amts) values('$product','$qty','$rate','$amts')");`

to the server side of code. Therefore it will skip the products that has no name.

Let me know if this is not how you want, and I will edit my code again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check your $_POST values and you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php)

```
$product = implode('#@$', array_filter($_POST["product"], function($var) {
  return isset($var)
}));
```

Additionally you should parse the values in a multidimensional array

```
$datas = [];

foreach ($_POST['product'] as $index => $product) {
  $product = isset($product) ? $product : null;
  $qty= isset($_POST['qty'][$index]) ? $_POST['qty'][$index] : null;
  $rate= isset($_POST['rate'][$index]) ? $_POST['rate'][$index] : null;
  $amount= isset($_POST['amount'][$index]) ? $_POST['amount'][$index] : null;

  if ($product && $qty && $rate && $amts) {
    $data[] = [
      'product' => $product,
      'qty' => $qty,
      'rate' => $rate,
      'amount' => $amount
    ];
  }
}
```

Now you can do something like this

```
<?php foreach ($datas as $data) { ?>
<input type="text" name="product[]" id="product{{$data['product']}}">
<input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty{{$data['qty']}}">
<input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate{{$data['rate']}}">
<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount{{$data['amount']}}">
<?php } ?>
```